# Why does Java Generics behave this way?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, generic-programming

I have an interface called `IUploader<T>` which has many abstract methods. One of them is `List<UploadErrors> getErrors()` method. The behaviour is given below.

```java
interface IUploader<T> {
    T parse();
    // some more abstract and default methods
    List<UploadErrors> getErrors();
}
```

```java
void someMethod(IUploader uploader) {
    // calling other methods of IUploader implementations
    List errors = uploader.getErrors(); // Problem - Getting List without type parameter
}
```

```java
<T> void someMethod(IUploader<T> uploader) {
    // calling other methods of IUploader implementations
    List<UploadErrors> errors = uploader.getErrors(); // Works fine
}
```

The problem here is, when I give type parameter for `IUploader` in `someMethod()`, I'm getting the local variable of `getErrors()` method as `List<UploadErrors>`. But without type parameter, I'm getting simply `List`. There is no relation between `<T>` and `UploadErrors`, but why this behaviour? The reason I have added Intellij IDEA is because, when I do `Alt+Enter` to "Introduce local variable", I get this two types. I have not tried in other IDEs. Please help me to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Using raw types erases _all generics_ related to the type.

Comment: @Slaw yes. But `UploadErrors` is not related to type `T`. Totally different

Comment: But it's related to the type `IUploader` and using a raw `IUploader` erases _all generics_ related to `IUploader`. And since `List<UploadErrors>` is using generics and is a return type of a method enclosed by `IUploader` it gets erased to `List` when using a raw `IUploader`.

Comment: When you use a raw type you're essentially using pre-generics code. In other words, in the context of the raw type generics may as well not exist.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting it now. So, I should always use generic type, If it has type parameter to not lose the genericity at anywhere

Comment: Yes, unless dealing with legacy code you should virtually never use raw types.